# viewForAnnotation Not Called Until Map is Moved

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

viewForAnnotation is not being called until I move or zoom in on the map. Because of this, my annotations do not show until the map is touched. Any idea why?

```
NSString *incident;
for (incident in weekFeed) {
     NSString *finalCoordinates = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [incident valueForKey:@"coordinates"]];

     NSArray *coordinatesArray = [finalCoordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 

     latcoord = (@"%@", [coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:0]);
     longcoord = (@"%@", [coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:1]);

     // Final Logs
     NSLog(@"Coordinates in NSString: [%@] - [%@]", latcoord, longcoord);

     CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
     coord.latitude = [latcoord doubleValue];
     coord.longitude = [longcoord doubleValue];


     DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
     ann.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [incident valueForKey:@"incident_type"]];
     ann.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [incident valueForKey:@"note"]];
     ann.coordinate = coord;

     [mapView addAnnotation:ann];

     [ann release];
}


// Custom Map Markers
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;  //return nil to use default blue dot view

    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
        }

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    if ([annotationView.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_1.png"];
        [annotationView setImage:pinImage];
        }

    if ([annotationView.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"two"]) {
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_2.png"];
        [annotationView setImage:pinImage];
        }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    return annotationView;
    }

- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapV didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    CGRect visibleRect = [mapV annotationVisibleRect]; 
    for (MKAnnotationView *view in views) {
        CGRect endFrame = view.frame;

        CGRect startFrame = endFrame; startFrame.origin.y = visibleRect.origin.y - startFrame.size.height;
        view.frame = startFrame;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"drop" context:NULL]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

        view.frame = endFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you adding ur annotation. I hope u are not adding it in mapView:regionDidChange: method

Comment: if not then it seems like your viewForAnnotation is only called if region is changed, so use mapView:setRegion:animated method to set the region programmatically and ur annotation will be displayed

Comment: Are you adding the annotations on the main thread? I've had all sorts of weird problems with MapKit and separate threads.

Comment: May not be the cause of your problem but in viewForAnnotation, the `annotationView.annotation = annotation;` line should be done _before_ the `if` statements that check the value of `annotationView.annotation.title`.

Comment: @xs2bush -- I am using `mapView:regionDidChange:` method.. but before I add the annotations. If I add that code after the annotations, it works, but then I'm stuck with a zoomed out globe while the annotations are loading.

Comment: @joerick -- I believe so... I'll double check. Thanks!

Comment: this will take us back to my first Q. In which method are you adding your annotations??? I do it in viewDidLoad all the time and it always works

Comment: I'm loading it on the main thread... viewDidLoad will be a bad user experience.. it will take too long to load all of my annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadEverything) withObject:self];` instead of `detachThreadSelector`. That code (in viewDidLoad) wasn't originally posted.

Thanks for helping everyone!